# CefSharp OffScreen has wrong values for width and height in window.screen where as CefSharp WinForms has correct values

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Our app is a background application which records screen using navigator.mediaDevices apis. Since it is a background application, we opted for CefSharp OffScreen. On investigation, I found out that recorded screen resolution is reduced one and with lower quality.

My Windows laptop resolution is 1920 x 1080
[image]

I compared below values in CefSharp Minimal Example project (OffScreen vs WinForms)

OffScreen: Here resolution is 1366 x 768
[image]

WinForms: Here resolution is 1920 x 1080 (resolution width = 1536 * 1.25 = 1920, resolution height = 864 * 1.25 = 1080) . These values align with chrome and firefox values.
[image]

What needs to be done to get correct screen resolution in CefSharp OffScreen similar to CefSharp Winforms ? Anyone please help

Or is there a way to run CefSharp Winforms as a background application without showing any UI ?

Additional note :

- I cannot preconfigure browser size because the same application needs to record multiple monitors
- In case of multiple monitors, resolution is reduced in the additional monitor in case of CefSharp Offscreen

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4769